# A seemingly complicated proof.

Tags: calculus

Let

$$ f(x) = (ax)^{\big(b\sin x\big)} $$
$$ g(x) = (x - \pi/2)(\sin x)^{\cfrac 1 {(x-\pi/2)}} $$
Also, let $ h(x) = g(x) - f(x) $ be defined in $(\pi/2, \pi) $

If $h(x)$ is an increasing function and $g(\pi/2) = 0$ then show that:
$$ 2(b)^{\cfrac 1 {1-b}} > a\pi$$

How to go about proving it?

**EDIT**
Ok, so here's how I started:

Since $h(x)$ is increasing, $h'(x) = g'(x) - f'(x) > 0$.

So, $g'(x) > f'(x)$.

So, $g'(\pi/2+) > f'(\pi/2+)$ [notation: $\pi/2+$ is a number greater than $\pi/2$ but in its neighborhood]

But the problem is, in $g'(\pi/2+)$, the power of $sinx$ tends to infinity, and it's multiplied by something tending to zero. Now, evaluating the limit of this would be quite nasty, no? And even then, we want to prove something that involves a $b$.

Comment: "Seemingly complicated"?!

Comment: Well, I thought it'd be...for some!! :D

Comment: The title gives no indication of the content.

Comment: I really couldn't think of anything better. If you have something, please share it with me!

Comment: Of what relevance is the value defined for $g$ at $\pi/2$? $h$ is only defined on $(\pi/2,\pi)$.

Comment: No clue...! Let's say h is defined on $[\pi/2, \pi]$, even then, what can be done?

Comment: "If h(x) is an increasing function and g(π/2)"... I don't understand that "if"; $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ were already defined above.

Comment: Good point! But maybe it's there just to direct us in our proof...?

Comment: One thing to try might be shifting everything over by $\pi/2$ and using a generalized binomial expansion... don't know if that will help.

Comment: OK, I'm thinking the trick is not to differentiate $h$ at all, but rather to calculate limits and/or values and compare them. The value at $\pi$ is $-1$, so everything else had better be less than that. Things get messier approaching $\pi/2$, but it certainly is between $-(a \pi/2)^b$ and $1-(a \pi/2)^b$, for whatever that's worth.